# Need guidance on Liferay parent/child structures & templates

Tags: templates, data-structures, nested, liferay-6

I am fairly new to Liferay, and just learning with EE 6.2.

I am trying to determine the RIGHT way to arrange structures, templates, and asset publishers for the following use case:

- Facilitate a large catalog of informational articles with custom fields and parent/child hierarchy, similar to (but not exactly) a wiki.
- Each article shares the same display page, where individual article content displays dynamically based on incoming url. (Passed in from another AP on another page)
- The current article and any parent or child articles should be listed hierarchically in a sidebar container/AP on the same page. (These related web content entries are not pages in and of themselves, so a basic Navigation/breadcrumbs portlet will not do.)
- Page layout uses multiple APs, most displaying various content from the current article of the custom structure (using multiple ADTs?), among other portlets.
- May not edit theme or core files. Any custom CSS is added to AP "look & feel".
- May not invoke servicelocator in display templates. Pages are public/guest.

So far, I have set a custom structure, and in order to complete that, I am prompted to add a custom template as well.

Next, I created another structure, and selected the first as the parent structure. The only added field is an integer where a user can assign a parent article by manually entering its ID. (Seems a horrid way to do this, but I can't find another way, given my ignorance + the above constraints.) I want to assign the same application display templates for both structures, but it doesn't seem to be an option. I had to create another template and name it as the child.

Then when I added an AP to my container page, I do not see either of the templates I just created as an option under Display Template. How do I select one of the custom templates I just made? Conversely, how can I access the custom fields of my structures when creating a new ADT, outside of the manage structures context?

Am I approaching this right? I haven't found any documentation or good use cases about actually displaying parent and child structures. (The only related material in their codex explains how to create a child structure, but not how to use it.) I'm also finding lots of frustration over the differences(?) between display templates and "application display templates". They all seem to do the same sort of thing but they are never all accessible from the same place!

So, simple version of my question is how do I set a custom AP display template to get content from both of my parent & child custom structures?

Thank you!